# Como exibir um item de um enum em minha table usando AngularJs?

Tags: c#, angularjs, enums

Eu tenho uma tabela em que faço um `ng-repeat`, até aqui normal.

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in itemsconfiguration">
                            <td>{{::item.Description}}</td>
                            <td>{{::item.Order}}</td>
                            <td>{{::item.Type}}</td>
                            <td><span ng-if="item.Active"></span></td>                            
                        </tr>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só que o campo Type da minha tabela que é um campo INT, eu teria que ao invés de exibir esse valor inteiro, exibir um item da minha tabela enum.

No meu controller eu já estou trazendo os enuns...

```
        AuditingItemType.query().$promise.then(function (itemtypes) {
        $scope.itemtypes = itemtypes;
    })
```

Json que recebo da tabela enum

```
[{"$id":"1","Id":0,"Name":"TEXT"},{"$id":"2","Id":1,"Name":"QUANTITY"},{"$id":"3","Id":2,"Name":"MULTIPLE"}]
```

como eu posso exibir ele em minha tabela dinamicamente?

Comment: Jhonas, seu enum já possui a annotation description?

Comment: Não...
    public enum AuditingItemType
    {
        TEXT,
        QUANTITY,
        MULTIPLE
    }

Comment: Está utilizando WebAPI 2.0?

Comment: Estou usando sim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é criar um `ng-repeat` interno, e filtrar o conteúdo - só exibir a descrição quando o valor de `Id` for igual ao `Type` do elemento referenciado pelo laço principal.

Exemplo a seguir:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {

  $scope.itemsconfiguration = [
    {"Description": "Secretaria", "Order": 2, "Type":2, "Active": 0},
    {"Description": "Patrimonio", "Order": 3, "Type":3, "Active": 1},
    {"Description": "Tesouraria", "Order": 2, "Type":2, "Active": 1}
  ];

  $scope.itemtypes = [
    {"$id":"1","Id":0,"Name":"TEXT"},
    {"$id":"2","Id":1,"Name":"QUANTITY"},
    {"$id":"3","Id":2,"Name":"MULTIPLE"},
    {"$id":"3","Id":3,"Name":"OTHER"}
  ];

}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">

      <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Descrição</th>
        <th>Ordem</th>
        <th>Tipo</th>
        <th>Ativo</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in itemsconfiguration">
          <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Order}}</td>
          <td>

            <span ng-repeat='type in itemtypes'
                  ng-if='type.Id == item.Type'>
              {{type.Name}}
            </span>

          </td>
          <td><span ng-if="item.Active">X</span></td>       
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```